# Python, printing over the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, printing

I am trying to print the progress my program made and I get an odd error. It seems if a for loop takes somewhat long time to finish, `end = "\r"` does not work properly.

For instance:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(f"Done {int(np.ceil(count*0.8))}% !", end = "\r")
    count += 1
```

prints `Done 5% !`

However

```
for i in range(6):
    print(f"Done {int(np.ceil(count*0.8))}% !", end = "\r")
    count += 1
    time.sleep(2)
```

prints `Done 1% !Done 2% !Done 3% !Done 4% !Done 4% !Done 5% !`

In my code a for loop turns for 70 seconds, so I thought the reason why progress update is not printed properly is because it takes too long?
I am unsure about the reason of this problem, what can be causing this?

Comment: In what application are you running this code? A terminal, an IDE...?

Comment: It could be that when the prints happen within a short time, they are buffered together and the final outcome is printed as it should be; but the application you are running the code in does not support carriage return, so if they are printed separately they do not get overwritten.

Comment: This is not answering your post, but might help. [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#tqdm) is a python library that does exactly what you need to do i.e showing the progress of a loop. You might want to check it.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the environment in which you're executing your code. Here's an example:-

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('Hello world\r')
sys.stdout.write('Hello world\n')
```

If I run this in Sublime Text, I see two lines:-

Hello world
Hello world

That's **not** what I would have hoped for.

However, if I run the script from a zsh terminal (macOS) I see one line:-

Hello world